# Someone else already reviewed a post, so my action is no longer required; should I review as "No Action Needed"?

Tags: support, review, new-users, late-answers

I see first-answer reviews where the answer is inappropriate, but someone else has already responded to it, welcoming the user and indicating what is wrong with the response.

There is obviously no need for me to add another comment.  "Skip" implies that I chose to ignore this item, so "No Action Needed" seems like a more correct response, as it provides information to the system.

But the "No Action Needed" button is titled with "*this answer seems to be valid*", and in this case the answer *isn't* valid.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: "No Action Needed" is the *wrong* response to pick in this situation. You should downvote or flag the answer. The tooltip is correct.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog, thanks.  Once an item has been reviewed, does it remain on the list for others to review it?  I.e. why did I get it if it had already been processed?  It wasn't obvious to me what I was expected to do.  This is the [specific example](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/61830) that inspired my question.

Comment: No; once a single user makes a review, no one else can.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog, thanks again.  It makes sense now.  In this case my confusion was a result of the first reviewer's forgetting to click the finished button.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the first reviewer's forgetting to click the finished button". The user who left the comment may have gone to the question on the site, without going through review. :)

Comment: @Catija, right.  Their response looked very much like how one would respond when doing a review.  Exactly how it happened isn't significant.  That it confused me, and that I now understand, is what's important.

Comment: @sonic There's no indication that the post was already reviewed. Only that it's already got a comment on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there's already a comment, upvote it!

That will allow you to complete the review.

Here's the list of actions that you can take - if you can't see the info, hit the (more) button - note, this is on questions but the answer one is the same except that "close" isn't an option.:

[image: first posts infobox]

> I'm Done is only available if you've done one of the following:
>
> - Vote up or down to rate the question's quality and usefulness
> - Edit to improve the question's appearance or clarity
> - Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up existing comments
> - Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems
> - Close questions that cannot or should not be answered here
> - Delete questions that are noise or of extremely poor quality

Any of these are valid options for this review item and you should take any and all of them that are appropriate. So, in some cases, you may want to comment and flag something as Not an Answer. In others, you may need to vote to close and downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The description of:

> this answer seems to be valid

is actually very correct. If there's anything wrong with the answer, you should be *doing* something, not just chosing "No action needed". You've actually got a lot of different options to complete a review in Late Answers:

- Upvote or downvote
- Edit
- Comment
- Upvote a comment
- Flag

If there's not a good reason to do any of those, then the answer is probably valid.